# Python pygame odd sequence

Tags: python

On my current Python script I have it counting down from 3 to 1, then taking a picture as you can intepret from this code below, doing this 4 times. However, it seems to sneak in 1 picture before counting down, and leaving the last one out, so the last countdown doesn't seem to matter.

Can anyone tell me why this is?

```
def start_photobooth():
    import config
    now = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y-%H:%M:%S")
    try:
        for i, filename in enumerate(camera.capture_continuous(config.images_path + now + '-' + '{counter:02d}.jpg')):
            print "[" + current_time() + "] [PHOTO] Producing " + filename
            surface.fill((0,0,0,0))
            surface.set_alpha(288)
            textSurfaceObj = fontObj.render('', True, red)
            surface.blit(textSurfaceObj, textRectObj)
            pygame.display.update()
            time.sleep(float(config.countdown)) 
            for y in range(3,0,-1):
                surface.fill((0,0,0,0))
                surface.set_alpha(288)
                textSurfaceObj = fontObj.render(str(y), True, red)
                surface.blit(textSurfaceObj, textRectObj)
                pygame.display.update()
                pygame.time.wait(1000)
            if i == total_pics-1:           
                break
```

Comment: could you format your python code with proper indentation ?

Comment: I've changed the indentation but my edit is waiting for "peer review"...

Comment: @elParaguayo How do you know that OP code is indented like this ?

Comment: Because if it was formatted as they'd posted then they'd be getting indentation errors and not the problems they were describing. I've therefore just fixed the obvious errors. If the OP has indented differently then they're free to change accordingly.

Comment: Which is the actual line that takes the picture? If it's the `camera.capture_continuous` then isn't it going to take a picture at the very beginning of the loop rather than after your countdown (at which point your loop restarts by taking another picture)?

Comment: @Hacketo I don't think my edits are visible yet.

Comment: @elParaguayo I am able to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will take a picture at the very beginning of your loop as the `capture_continuous` method is executed at that point.

Your code will then run its countdown and restart the loop at which point it takes another photo.

What your loop is really doing is just:

- Take picture
- Countdown
- Repeat

You want it to be:

- Countdown
- Take picture
- Repeat

You could therefore change the start of your loop to:

```
for i in range(total_pics):
```

remove the `if` section at the end of your code (as this is handled by the `for` loop now) and insert a line to take the photo after the countdown. Assuming this is rasperry pi camera then the line would be:

```
filename = camera.capture("{0}{1}-{2:02d}.jpg".format(config.images_path,now,i))
```

I'm not familiar with the picamera module, so it may be that you do it this way:

```
filename = "{0}{1}-{2:02d}.jpg".format(config.images_path,now,i)
camera.capture(filename)
```

Comment: That makes sense. I'm convinced this is the right answer. Thank you!

Comment: Great. Give it a go and if it doesn't work then come back and explain what's not working.

Comment: It works, but now it's unable to spit out "filename" and "{counter:02d}" properly, causing it not to properly save pictures.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks!